# Word Doc - Page Numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

I would like to add page numbers to a book but I don't want page 1 to start from the first page (as books don't do this). Does anyone know how I can start the page numbers from a few pages into the book, not the first page? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the book into sections, each with (or without)
its page-numbering scheme.

See
[Insert a section break](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c).

It's quite common for books to have one numbering schema for the
Table of Contents and another for the book text.